# Eye-to-hand camera calibration, location of the calibration board

Tags: python, calibration, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the Moveit [camera calibration plugin](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/hand_eye_calibration/hand_eye_calibration_tutorial.html) for the eye-to-hand calibration, what is the required position for the calibration board?

I understand that the board needs to be rigidly mounted on the arm end effector link, but how exactly? Same orientation of the end effector link? Can there be an offset in x,y,z or the camera w.r.t. the end effector link? If so, how is this offset communicated to the calibration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383047/eye-to-hand-camera-calibration,-location-of-the-calibration-board/) by [lorepieri](https://answers.ros.org/users/60501/lorepieri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2021-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There will always be an offset in translation and rotation between your end effector and the calibration board. But that offset is not important, as long as it does not change during the calibration process. That's why it is important to ensure the calibration board is "rigidly connected" to the end effector.

Generally, it is sufficient to make the calibration board reasonably rigid (no visible bending under its own load, or vibrations after robot movements) and attach it to the end effector with whatever method you have readily available. By grasping the board with your robot gripper or screwing it to the robot flange, for example.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1